# Replace instance based on array's index

Tags: .net, regex, string, vb.net, replace

I'm looking to replace all occurence "[2]" in a given string
Here is my current function

```
Dim replace() As String
replace = Split("3,2,4,1", ",")
Dim orig As String = "[2] [2] [2] [2]"
Dim search As String = "[2]"
 sb = New StringBuilder(orig)
For i As Integer = 0 To replace.Length - 1

                Dim Occurrence = sb.ToString().IndexOf(search)
                If Occurrence > -1 Then
                    If (replace(j) = "2") Then
                        sb.Replace(search, "[2]", firstOccurrence, search.Length)
                     j = j + 1
                    Else
                        sb.Replace(search, "[" & replace(j) & "]", firstOccurrence, search.Length)
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                End If

            Next
```

Actually i get this :

```
Output : [3] [4] [1] [2]
```

I'm looking to get something like this:

```
Output : [3] [2] [4] [1]
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are replacing with what you already have you need to keep track of the start point of your next search each time

```
Dim Occurrence = sb.ToString().IndexOf(search, Occurance)
```

And you already know the position so

```
sb.Replace(search, "[2]", Occurrence, search.Length)
```

or

```
sb.Replace(search, "[" & replace(j) & "]", Occurrence, search.Length)
```

and end with

```
Occurance += search.Length
```

And don't use variable names like search and replace in routines like this. It's just confusing.... and looks like function calls. When you come back to your code in six months you will thank me.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to keep track of where to start searching from, and also you could greatly simplify that loop and make it easier to maintain by removing all those one-letter indexes. That said, your goal could be accomplished like this:

```
    Dim orig As String = "[2] [2] [2] [2]"
    Dim searchText As String = "[2]"
    Dim replaceChars() As String = Split("3,2,4,1", ",")
    Dim startIndex As Integer = 0

    For replaceIndex As Integer = 0 To replaceChars.Count - 1
        Dim searchIndex As Integer = orig.IndexOf(searchText, startIndex) + 1
        orig = orig.Remove(searchIndex, 1).Insert(searchIndex, replaceChars(replaceIndex))
        startIndex = searchIndex
    Next

    MsgBox(orig)
```

Note the startindex variable, it's used to tell IndexOf where to start searching...and at the end of each loop, it is updated to the last position where a match was found. This keeps IndexOf from searching the entire string during the next iteration

Comment: Issue with that solution though is it gets to be a big memory hog in a larger data scenario. All that string changing isn't well handled by VB

Comment: I agree, it also doesn't account for if there were more than 4 occurences of "[2]" so it wouldn't be a great thing to just copy/paste and use...so OP use this as an example of how the startIndex can be used, but there are some other issues that need to be thought through as well

Comment: thank you for your help, actually i have 80files(answers) and 80files(questions) with larger data.. i'll use something like this orig = File.ReadAllText("F:\\" & filname & ".csv") , replace = Split(File.ReadAllText("F:" & filname & ".txt")  and i will end with something like this File.WriteAllText("F:\" & filname & ".csv", sb.ToString) i think i'll use big memory

Answer (score 0):

Cheap and dirty solution

```
    Dim Values() As String = {"3", "2", "4", "1"}
    Dim Orig As String = "[2] [2] [2] [2]"
    Dim Output As String = Replace(Orig, "[2]", "[^]")
    For Each ReplaceMent As String In Values
        Output = Replace(Output, "[^]", "[" & ReplaceMent & "]", 1, 1)
    Next
    'Put back any unused twos
    Output = Replace(Output, "[^]", "[2]")
```

Comment: Your second answer is more clear, using the Occurrence += replace.Length, thank you

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do to make this quick is split your string on the substring you’re trying to replace, so this string:

```
one[2]two[2]three[2]four[2]five
```

becomes an array with five elements:

```
{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
```

Once you have that, you can “zip” it together with your replacements:

```
  {"one",    "two",    "three",    "four",    "five"}
& {"[3]",    "[2]",    "[4]",      "[1]"}
-----------------------------------------
  {"one[3]", "two[2]", "three[4]", "four[1]", "five"}
```

and join the whole thing back together:

```
one[3]two[2]three[4]four[1]five
```

In code, that looks like this:

```
Dim replace As String() = {"[3]", "[2]", "[4]", "[1]"}
Dim orig = "[2] [2] [2] [2]"
Dim search = "[2]"

Dim result = String.Concat(
    orig.Split({search}, StringSplitOptions.None).Zip(
        Enumerable.Concat(replace, {""}),
        Function (a, b) a & b
    )
)
```

It’s probably a good idea to split this into another function, too:

```
<Extension>
Function ReplaceSequence(s As String, find As String, replacements As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
    Return String.Concat(
        s.Split({find}, StringSplitOptions.None).Zip(
            Enumerable.Concat(replacements, {""}),
            Function (a, b) a & b
        )
    )
End Function
```

which can then be used like so:

```
Dim result = "[2] [2] [2] [2]".ReplaceSequence(
    "[2]",
    {"[3]", "[2]", "[4]", "[1]"}
)
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Though changing the source data is cheating LOL

Comment: @Trevor: I wanted to ease it into the reusable function, but from there it’s okay to `"3,2,4,1".Split({","c}).Select(Function (n) "[" & n & "]")`.

Comment: Ya I started toying with splitting it into an array, but the example is a little too simple and it gets complicated quickly for different lengths of values and originals. A better solution might be to just do a quick replace on the original to change it from [2] to something else so he isn't putting back what he took out. To answer the original question I mean.

Comment: @Trevor: Does it? I’m pretty sure the `ReplaceSequence` function here works for values of varying lengths.

Comment: No I meant my splitting solution. Though he really doesn't mention what to do if there are more [2]s than values.... It's a weird setup from the beginning.